# Why form not submitting with models in asp.net mvc 5 .(Another Model binding error)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my mvc application i have a script  with following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var element = $('input[data-op-mode="Edit"]');
        $(".form-control").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        element.click(function() {

            var elementValue = element.val();
            if (elementValue == "Edit") {
                element.val("Update");
                $(".form-control").removeAttr("disabled");
               return false; //blocking from submitting form
            } else {
                $(".form-control").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                element.val("Edit");
             return true;

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The purpose this code is to toggle Edit->Update, Update->Edit. This functionality is working fine . but when submitting the form the the post method not submitting the form values to my controller (model binding not working). the html code is given below

```
@model AutoPosContextA.DomainModels.Customer
@{

    var options = new AjaxOptions()
                      {
                          Url = Url.Action("Update", "Customer"),
                          LoadingElementId = "saving",
                          LoadingElementDuration = 1000,
                          OnFailure = "OnAjaxCallsFailed",
                          OnSuccess = "OnCustomerInsertSuccess"
                      };
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(options))
{
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i><input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn-link"  data-op-mode="Edit"/></li>
        <li> <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#mainDiv" href="/Customer/ListCustomer"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i>&nbsp;Cancel</a></li>
        <li> <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#mainDiv" href="/Customer/CreateCustomer"><i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>&nbsp;Clear</a></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="clear: both">

            <tr>
                <td><label for="CustomerName"  >Customer name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="CustomerName" placeholder="Customer name" name="CustomerName" value="@Model.CustomerName"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="AddressLine1"  >AddressLine-1</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="AddressLine1" placeholder="AddressLine-1" name="AddressLine1" value="@Model.AddressLine1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="AddressLine1"  >AddressLine-2</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="AddressLine2" placeholder="AddressLine-2" name="AddressLine2" value="@Model.AddressLine2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="Mobile"  >Mobile</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Mobile" placeholder="Mobile" name="Mobile" value="@Model.Mobile"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="CustomerKey"  >Search Key(s)</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="CustomerKey" placeholder="" name="CustomerKey" value="@Model.CustomerKey"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="Notes"  >Notes</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Notes" placeholder="Notes" name="Notes" value="@Model.Notes"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" name="Id" id="Id"/>
    </div>
}
```

The key point in my problems are
1.) If i remove the script it will work fine 
2.) Here i am using strongly typed partial view

**Whats wrong with my javascript?**

Comment: The problem solved .It due to "disabled" attribute.The disabled attribute block reading value from form fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabled form fields are not sent back to the server by the browser in a POST request (according to HTTP standards), so the MVC framework will not have the values to do the model binding before entering your controller.

Potential solutions

1. Avoid using disabled and mix some css and javascript to obtain the feeling of disabled for fields.
2. On form submit event make sure to enable all the fields back
3. Put some hidden fields in the form with the names from the controls, and update them every time a value changes.